# How do you switch between languages on local setups?

Tags: java, ruby, installation, local

On my local windows 8 setup I have Ruby on Rails env already set up. I'd like to install Java as well without removing RoR and be able to use either from the terminal depending on what project I'm working on. How do switch from one language environment to another and back again when I'm done working on any specific thing?

Comment: You can install both and use both of them. You can add both Java and Ruby to your PATH variable. Don't see why you would not be able to do that.

Comment: On my dev machine, I happen to have a Rust, Go, Node.js, Ruby, and Python configured, with no switching required. As long as there are no name conflicts in the tools (and between Ruby/RoR and Java, I doubt there would be) you should be good to just install and go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as both Java and Ruby are included in your PATH environmental variable, you will not have to do anything to "switch".  Simply change to the directory of your other project and work as normal.

Comment: Got it. I thought I'd have to change over to a different environment somehow. Thank you.

Comment: Make sure to mark resolved!

Comment: I hadn't hit the time limit when I tried before